# Conditionally Quasi-random Choices and Qualitative Dependent Variable Models

Tags: probability, categorical-data, combinatorics, ordered-logit

I have a scenario about limited dependent variable models and some of their implications. Suppose that I estimate some limited dependent model, it does not really matter which one, that captures the factors that affect the choice of time when $N$ individuals go to a doctor's appointment. We assume that there are only $T$ discrete times when I can attend. Firstly, would it be true if:

$P(y_i=1|x_i)=P(y_i=2|x_i)=...=P(y_i=T)=\frac{1}{T}$

then, conditional on the covariates, the doctor appointment times are quasi-randomly chosen by each individual? Secondly, and more importantly, am I correct that this would imply that any given vector of treatment times has a $\frac{1}{N^T}$ chance of being realized? My thinking is that here we are dealing with permutations with $N$ individuals and $T$ options for each person, hence the number of possible N-tuples is $N^T$. The above then suggests that any one of these is equally likely. Hence, the probability must be $1/N^T$.

Any help would be appreciated!